Issues with setting bios password in dell command update from command line
So I am trying to create a powershell script for my organizations imaging process and part of that is installing drivers. I am trying to make this so a admin can set one and let it go and come back and its done.
What Im running-
$var = $env:COMPUTERNAME.ToLower()
.\dcu-cli.exe -biospassword=$var

This always returns error 104 which means the syntax is wrong, what is the corrected syntax?
The dell website says to add "" around the password or in this case variable, no dice. I also tried piping it, no change in result either. It always returns er 104.

You are missing double quotes (https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/command-update/dellcommandupdate_rg/dell-command-update-cli-commands?guid=guid-92619086-5f7c-4a05-bce2-0d560c15e8ed&lang=en-us)  Try .\dcu-cli.exe -biospassword="$var"

Try $var = $('"' + $env:COMPUTERNAME.ToLower() + '"') in an attempt to force the double quotes.

The proper syntax for changing the BIOS password with Dell Command | Update CLI command is:
dcu-cli.exe /configure -biosPassword="Test1234"

So, in your case, you are missing the /configure command option as well as enclosing the password string with double quotes.  Note that per official documentation indicated the value must be enclosed in double quotes.
Reference: Dell Command | Update Version 5.x Reference Guide

Powershell is funny with double quotes and external programs. You may need backslashes (powershell 5.1), and at least single quotes, if those double quotes are mandatory.
dcu-cli /configure -biosPassword='\"Test1234\"'
dcu-cli /configure -biosPassword='"Test1234"'

Tested with echoargs.
